# Autosize not working of Table Layout Panel in Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I am making a windows application,in which i am using a table layout panel, structure of table layout panel is:

```
Total columns are : 1 -> Autosize
Total rows are : 6 -> Autosize
```

In the code behind i am adding 4 radio buttons and text of radio buttons are a bit long and i dont want that text in a single line, i want something like line-wrap property,code for adding radio buttons is :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            rbtn1 = new RadioButton();
            rbtn1.Name = "rbtn" + (i + 1);
            rbtn1.Text = "A jogger running at 9 kmph alongside a railway track in 280 metres ahead of the engine of a 120 metres long train running at 45 kmph in the same direction. In how much time will the train pass the jogger?";
            rbtn1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            rbtn1.Font = new Font("Verdana", 10);
            tableLayoutQuestionAnswer.Controls.Add(rbtn1, 1, i+1);
        }
```

my final result is : [image]

Text after "train" is not appearing . What will be the solution for this, i am trying this from last 2 days, need help, thanks a lot.

Comment: This question is marked as a duplicate of a question that doesn't exist?  How do we get that stigma removed?

Answer (score 0):

If you set radiobutton's AutoSize value to false, and specify Width value, words will be wrapped.

```
rdbButton.AutoSize = false;
rdbButton.Width = 100;
```

Comment: i tried it but it's not working

Comment: This doesn't work.